# Getting 1 week data from firestore database with flutter

Tags: flutter, firebase, dart, google-cloud-firestore

[image]

I want to pull last 1 week data from firestore database
but the data is not coming, where, what did I do, even I don't know, can you help me?

```
DateTime birHaftaOnce = DateTime.now().subtract(Duration(days: 7));
Timestamp birHaftaOnceTimestamp = Timestamp.fromDate(birHaftaOnce);

QuerySnapshot snapshot = await FirebaseFirestore.instance
    .collection('ogrenciler').where('tc', isEqualTo: widget.tc)
    .where('tarih', isGreaterThanOrEqualTo: birHaftaOnceTimestamp)
     .orderBy('tarih', descending: true).get();
      
      if (snapshot.docs.isNotEmpty) {
        for (QueryDocumentSnapshot documentSnapshot in snapshot.docs) {
            print(documentSnapshot.data());
        }
      } else {
          print('Veri yok');
      }
```

Answer (score 1):

Your query is ordering the documents by the value of their `tarih` field. But looking at the screenshot you shared there is no `tarih` field in the root of the document.

Instead there is an `gunlukDers` array field, where each individual array element has a `tarih` value. But you want query for such a subfield.

The solution is to add a top-level field that indicates the date to each of your documents, and then query on that.

An alternative would be to give each of the documents you show now a `gunlukDers` **subcollection** with the data you now store in the array and then query *that*.

Comment: .where('gunlukDers.tarih', isGreaterThanOrEqualTo: birHaftaOnceTimestamp)
    .orderBy('gunlukDers.tarih', descending: true);                                                                                why edit this way doesn't work

Comment: The tarih field must be next to the ders_alindimi field